# Disabling Acrobat Reader's automatic updates

Tags: adobe-acrobat

Having installed Adobe Acrobat Reader (acroread) from the Canonical Partner repository on a client computer (Ubuntu 12.04), I was asked if I could turn off the automatic updates.

So, does Acrobat Reader update itself or are the updates handled by the package managers like for all the other programs?

And how to disable automatic updates for Acrobat Reader?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if Acrobat Rearder is installed using deb, you hold the package in the following way echo "package hold" | sudo dpkg --set-selections

Comment: I did not download a deb-file from Adobe's webpage, if that is what you mean. As mentioned, it is installed from the Canonical Partner repository. But does that command still work?

Comment: in the repository you have deb files and this file are manipulate by apt, use the command "dpkg -l | grep -i adobe"

Comment: I see. Well, I tried it and it seemed to work fine. Thanks!